# Assigning multiple documents in library to one item in custom list (and vice-versa)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have to move tariffs to Sharepoint and assign them to the proper customers.  I have created a Custom List with all of our customers and a Document Library with all the tariffs.  My issue is that there isn't always a one-to-one relationship.  One tariff could be assign to several customers and one customer could have several tariffs assigned to it.  I was reading about Document Sets but I don't think it would apply.  Any suggestions??  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

that kind of relation data is not something that SharePoint out of the box handles very well. So in many cases these requirements would be handled by 3rd party add ons or perhaps in a Power App where the interface to an eg. customer and tariff lists could be handled.

In your situation I would recommend setting up a "Look up" field on the Tariffs list that points to the customer list. For the list you allow multiple values.

This way each Tariff can be related to several customers, and each customers can have several Tariffs assigned to them. I think this will handle your requirement "OK". :)